# is there a way to remove css from vuetify elements and then add your own

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to add my own css to override the vuetify v-select element

I've tried to add a class to the element, but it just adds the css underneath the vuetify element

````
  <div>
    <VSelect
      v-model="value"
      :items="sortOptions"
      item-text="text"
      :return-object="true"
      class="rectangle"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="styl">
  .rectangle {
    height: 40px;
    width: 144px;
    border: 1px solid #CCD8DB;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: var(--v-dgrey-lighten3);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
  }
</style>```
````

Comment: yes...like [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qGGEvB)?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add "!important" on your own css to override. Example:

```
height: 40px !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr; `Vuetify({ styles: 'none' })` in `vite.config`

**Details:**

so, using `!important` is not a good solution (at least not for me).

it turns out that there is a simple setting `styles: 'none'` as part of `vuetify`... just open your `vite.config` and add it there:

```
    Vuetify({ styles: 'none' }),
```

btw, by running `yarn create vuetify` (as described in https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#installation) you can create your brand new project and then it'll contain a `vite.config.mts` which will have `Vuetify()`... all you have to do is add the `{ styles: 'none' }` as above.

hopefully it's helpful to other people...